# VC Dimension generalized to discrete, non-binary, unordered domains?

Tags: reference-request, lg.learning, vc-dimension

VC dimension is a measure of the complexity of classes of functions $f:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ that is closely tied to sample complexity. Fat shattering dimension is a generalization suited to richer ordered domains: i.e. $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is there a standard generalization of VC-dimension suited to functions with discrete, unordered domains? i.e. $f:X\rightarrow K$ where $K$ is a finite set with no ordering on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - I think you are looking for "multiclass VC dimension," and there are a couple different generalizations of VC dimension to multiclass classification.  A good [paper](http://mercurio.srv.dsi.unimi.it/~cesabian/Pubblicazioni/jcss-95.pdf) on this is by Ben-David et al. ('95). In addition to proving learnability results, they give a nice history and references to previous extensions of VC dimension to the multiclass case.  Another perhaps relevant [work](http://www.phillong.info/publications/sauer.pdf) by Haussler and Long ('95) generalizes Sauer's lemma to more general versions of VC dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension characterizing multiclass learnability (i.e., the "correct" multiclass analog of VC-dimension) has recently been discovered:
Nataly Brukhim, Daniel Carmon, Irit Dinur, Shay Moran, Amir Yehudayoff:
A Characterization of Multiclass Learnability.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.01550